# How can I use 'this' jquery selector with angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, this

I try to use below code.

```
$('button').click(() => {
   console.log($('button').index(this)); // should show clicked element index
   //but in angular2 can't use 'this' 
})
```

I know if I used 'let i = index' if I use ngFor...
but I have to use 'd3.js'

How can I use 'this' selector with angular 2?

or there have another way to get selected element index number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `event.currentTarget` instead of `this`:

```
$('button').click((e) => {
   console.log($('button').index(e.currentTarget));
})
```

See also

- https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Comment: If I want to use .each() how can I do?




        $('button').each(() => {
              $(this).attr('color');
        }

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function `function
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )` Second parameter will refer to current element